# What is this weird thing on Sublime Text 3 status bar?

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

On the left side of my Sublime Text 3 status bar, there is very weird rectangle made by red and yellow vertical stripes. Is that a glitch?

[image]

Comment: I believe it is the graphic that is displayed when a theme's resource can't be loaded - what theme are you using and does it go away if you use the Default theme?

Comment: I'm using Agila Dracula theme and yes - it goes away when I switch to some other theme :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sublime Text Build 3101 (Release Date: 5 February 2016) introduced a new "Panel Switcher" widget to the status bar.

If the theme you are using hasn't been updated to include a graphic for it, then the red and yellow vertical stripes are displayed in place. This is what ST usually shows when a theme's resource can't be loaded.

Probably you should submit an issue to the theme's issue tracker.

https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/dev-build-3101/17027/40